# Calling a variable from a different column or table inside a value

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `ProductInfo` in my database. This table contains text descriptions of specific products. Just a text field called `description`, picture url etc.

I have another table called `Locations`. In this table I have company names, city names (New York, Boston, Omaha etc.)

What I want to be able to do is insert the variables from the `Locations` table into the text field for the descriptions in the `ProductInfo` table.

So.. in my `ProductInfo` table I have an entry called "Widget" and it has a description. I would like to be able to do the following:

> This widget is the best widget money can buy. If you live in the (`$city1`, `$city2`, `$city3`) area then you simply must by this widget from (`$company_name`). (`$company_name`) specializes in providing (`$service1`) for clients living in the (`$city 4`), (`$state`) areas.

Can anyone provide some insight as to how I might be able to do this. I guess it would be nesting variables inside other variables, but i am not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution to this depends a lot on how flexible you need it to be. Just inserting concatenated values from one record into another is easy, and it's possible to concatenate values from several records together and do the same. Doing it without using stored procedures (or external scripting) is likely to be tricky. Can you post some exact examples of table contents (indicating the relationships you're using)?

Comment: @Johan, I think Dax is looking for a pure SQL answer

Answer (score 0):

Dax, I have very little info to go on, but here's a query that would combine fields from three tables:

```
Location
  id integer not null autoincrement primary key
  company_id integer not null
  city varchar not null
  FOREIGN KEY company_id REFERENCES company.id ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

Company
  id integer not null autoincrement primary key
  companyname varchar not null
  service varchar not null
  city varchar not null
  state varchar not null
  ....other fields...

ProductInfo
  id integer not null autoincrement primary key
  company_id integer not null
  productname varchar ....
  FOREIGN KEY company_id REFERENCES company.id ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

This query would produce the info that you require.

```
SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT l.city ORDER BY l.city SEPARATOR ', ') AS city
  , c.companyname
  , c.service
  , c.city
  , c.state
FROM location l
INNER JOIN productInfo pi ON (pi.company_id = l.company_id)
INNER JOIN company c ON (pi.company_id = c.id)
WHERE pi.id = 589
GROUP BY pi.id
```

The main trick is accomplished by `GROUP_CONCAT`,
see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat
If you use `group_concat` you must also include a `group by` clause.

Good luck.